# send email with attachment in Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm using `EmailMultiAlternatives` to send email with html content.

I also need to send .docx file as an attachment in the mail.

I used `message.attach_file('/tmp/file.docx')` but I getting error as `No such file or directory is found` even though path is correct.

I also tried with `EmailMessage` using `message.content_subtype` to include html_content, but still the same error with .docx attachment.

I also want to try `message.attach('filename', content, 'mimetype'`)--> here I don't know what exactly to include in the contentspace. How do I solve this?

Email Client is Outlook

- Django Version - 1.11
- Python Version - 3.6

Comment: is the file in that location?

Comment: yes, it is in that location.

Comment: How did you ensured the path to file is valid ? Did you call `os.path.exists()` to check the same path is correct ? Checking the path manually is not sufficient here, since it appear the path is actually NOT valid...

Comment: @Antwane yes I checked it using `os.path.exists()`, the path exists and I also gave the permissions to project folder.